# Can't run Realm with React not native

Tags: realm

Created my react app with react-create-app. Installed realm and included it. Get the following error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in
>   ./node_modules/realm/lib/browser/index.js'

It's true that the file requires react-native but my application isn't React Native, it's just React. Installing react-native module anyway does not solve this.

I've tried to use include Realm in a simple javascript file and run it with Node (No React included). It worked. What could cause this to fail in my project? The start script I am using?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask a question. For example: `What could cause this to fail in my project? The start script I am using?` This is impossible to answer, how can we know what's in your start script?

Comment: Thank you! The start script is the standard one included in react-create-app.  It's a module that helps you get started with your react project. Just trying to theorize whether it had something to do with webpack.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the documentation: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#getting-started